# Como faço para salvar uma imagem em um caminho, buscando de uma base Oracle?

Tags: php, oracle, gd

Estou tentando com a biblioteca GD do PHP, dessa maneira:

```
<?php
$con = oci_connect('root', '123', '172.16.1.100/DB');
$stmt = oci_parse($con, "SELECT Nome, Imagem FROM Tabela where ID = '1'");
oci_execute($stmt);

$row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
if (!$row) {
    header('Status: 404 Not Found');
} else {
    $assinatura = $row['IMAGEM'];
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    $imagem = imagecreatefrompng($assinatura);
    imagepng($imagem,"img-".$row['NOME'].".png");
    imagedestroy($imagem);
}
?>
```

Porém não salva. Se eu dou um print $assinatura ele aparece a imagem certinho.

Comment: Não deve ser isso, mas tenta sem o `imagedestroy($imagem);`.

Comment: Também não deu certo @AndreiCoelho

Comment: O que vem do banco já é o conteúdo do arquivo? Você não faz nenhuma manipulação? Se sim, então você não precisa da biblioteca GD, você pode salvar direto o binário do arquivo usando file_put_contents por exemplo.

Comment: Ele vem em vários caracteres especiais @JúlioNeto, se fosse somente para pegar na Base e mostrar eu até consigo. Porém, eu gostaria de pegar a imagem da Base Oracle e salvar em um local para somente salvar o caminho dela em outra Base.

Comment: É estranho esse código não funcionar. Principalmente porque você conseguiu printar a imagem... Com o `var_dump(imagepng($imagem,"img-".$row['NOME'].".png"));` retorna o que?

Comment: Eu errei no enunciado, quando dou `print $assinatura` ele mostra a imagem, em vez do `$imagem`.. o `var_dump()` retornou `null` em `$imagem` e em `$assinatura` retorna '�PNG

���
IHDR�������:���_��0���IDATx��GoA��/wD�b2�"��E'rGD�Y؀9�Ӊ�A�F_K�j�ݳ;����[%Y������ͫW�=n7�>' e isso continua.. @AndreiCoelho

Comment: Isso retirando o `header("Content-type: image/png")` para não tentar printar alguma imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver, não do jeito que eu queria, mas deu certo!

Primeiro eu converti os caracteres especiais com `base64_encode($assinatura)` e inseri na outra Base (MySQL). Depois recuperei esses dados com

```
print base64_decode($assinatura); 
header("Content-type: image/png");
```

Caso alguém tenha outra solução..

Comment: legal! Ainda sim é bom "investigar" o motivo para não ter dado certo.

Comment: Pelo que eu vi @AndreiCoelho, o `imageCreateFromPng()` espera um local onde esteja a imagem (um arquivo ou URL) e retorna `null` caso dê erro. [Referencia](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)